# Repartition with Apache Spark

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

**The problem**: I am trying to repartition a dataset so that all rows that have the same number in a specified column of intergers are in the same partition.

**What is working**: when I use the 1.6 API (in Java) with RDD I use a hash partitioner and this work as expected. For example if I print the modulo of each value of this column for each row I get the same modulo in a given partition (I read the partition by manually reading the content saved with saveAsHadoopFile).

It is not working as expected with the latest API

But now I am trying to use the 2.0.1 API (in Scala) and the Datasets which have a repartition method that take a number of partitions and a column and save this DataSet as a parquet file. The results are not the same if I look in the partitions the rows are not haspartitioned given this column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To save partitioned `Dataset` you can use either:

- `DataFrameWriter.partitionBy` - available since Spark 1.6

  ```
  df.write.partitionBy("someColumn").format(...).save()
  ```
- `DataFrameWriter.bucketBy` - available since Spark 2.0

  ```
  df.write.bucketBy("someColumn").format(...).save()
  ```

Using `df.partitionBy("someColumn").write.format(...).save` should work as well but `Dataset` API doesn't use hashcodes. It uses `MurmurHash` so results will be different than the results from `HashParitioner` in RDD API and trivial checks (like the one you described) won't work.

```scala
val oldHashCode = udf((x: Long) => x.hashCode)

// https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L1596-L1599
val nonNegativeMode = udf((x: Int, mod: Int) => {
  val rawMod = x % mod
  rawMod + (if (rawMod < 0) mod else 0)
})

val df = spark.range(0, 10)

val oldPart = nonNegativeMode(oldHashCode($"id"), lit(3))
val newPart = nonNegativeMode(hash($"id"), lit(3))

df.select($"*", oldPart, newPart).show
```

```
+---+---------------+--------------------+
| id|UDF(UDF(id), 3)|UDF(hash(id, 42), 3)|
+---+---------------+--------------------+
|  0|              0|                   1|
|  1|              1|                   2|
|  2|              2|                   2|
|  3|              0|                   0|
|  4|              1|                   2|
|  5|              2|                   2|
|  6|              0|                   0|
|  7|              1|                   0|
|  8|              2|                   2|
|  9|              0|                   2|
+---+---------------+--------------------+
```

One possible gotcha is that `DataFrame` writer can merge multiple small files to reduce the cost so data from different partitions can be put in a single file.

Comment: Thanks ! I just tested your example with bucketBy as it seem to do exactly what I want (the row with the same numbers in the given collumn in the same partition) but at some point in execution I get `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'save' does not support bucketing right now;`

Comment: I have similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434262/writing-partition-data-into-single-file-in-spark) but i want to write the data with some custom logic. Hence, can't use write method directly. Can you please help?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue where I'm loading a dataframe, partitioning it and sorting by a column and then writing it using save(). I get the same error "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'save' does not support bucketing right now". Could you please explain how you resolved this?